# implement ObservableList, extend ObservableListWrapper

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to create a class that is almost identical to the object returned by `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` but with some extra functionality. My first thought was something like

```
public class MyObservableList implements ObservableList
{
    private ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public functionWhatever()
    {
        // whatever
    }

}
```

but that means overriding the ~30 functions that come with `ObservableList` (which seems like a hint that I'm doing something wrong).

`FXCollections.observableArrayList()` returns an object of type `com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper`, but when I extend `ObservableListWrapper` I'm required to create a constructor like

```
MyObservableList( List arg0 )
```

or

```
MyObservableList( List arg0, Callback arg1 )
```

which worries me because `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` doesn't accept any arguments.

I don't know how `FXCollections` creates the `ObservableListWrapper` object that it returns but I want `MyObservableList` to be identical to the object returned by `FXCollections` (plus a couple extra functions).

How do I do this?

Comment: `ObservableList` implements `List` and `Observable`. What if you made your list, making it inherit from a `List`-implementing class and `Observable` instead of `ObservableList`, or do you need to use it for something that requires `ObservableList`?

Comment: The problem is that JavaFX uses ObservableList all over the place. The official way to create an ObservableList object is via FXCollections.observableArrayList(). I want the objects created by my class to be identical (because who knows what will change in the future) but with additional functions.

Comment: Could You use a wrap-up delegate?

Comment: If you want your list to be truly identical to the ones returned by `FXCollections`, you'd have to subclass `ObservableListWrapper`, but since this is a `com.sun.*` class you really shouldn't. There is no guarantee that the API of that class will remain the same in future releases, which might lead to conflics with your subclass' methods. Question is: Why would you want that in the first place? Implementing the `ObservableList` interface may be ugly, but in this case it's the safe and correct approach.

Comment: With JavaFX 8+, you can just extend `ObservableListBase` (or one of its subclasses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend **SimpleListProperty** [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleListProperty.html)

*This class provides a full implementation of a Property wrapping an ObservableList.*

---

Notice this ctor:

*public SimpleListProperty(ObservableList initialValue)*

So you can:

```
public class MyObservableList extends SimpleListProperty
{
    //constructor
    MyObservableList(){
        super(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    }

    public functionWhatever()
    {
        // whatever
    } 

}
```

This way your class will be based on a ArrayList.